# Stop multiline GitHub action on first fail

Tags: github-actions

We have a GitHub action for building our app
We're using the multiline syntax.

```
run: |
  npm install
  npm run test
  npm run e2e
  npm run deploy
```

If one on the commands fail, the action continue to the next command and will deploy the app.

Is there a way to abort the action on first fail?

Comment: That's surprising, according to [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-a-specific-shell), shell commands run with `bash --noprofile --norc -eo pipefail`, where `-e` should cause exit on error.

Comment: @BenjaminW. the documentation might have been updated since you commented, but it now says it's not applied by default unless you specify `shell: bash`.

Answer (score 2):

This probably occurs on a Windows runner and can be fixed by [ensuring the default shell for the job](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/setting-default-values-for-jobs#example-setting-default-run-step-options-for-a-job) is `bash`:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    # ...etc...
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
```

That will make it use `bash --noprofile --norc -eo pipefail` even on Windows runners.

Comment: The default if you don't set the shell is still `bash -e`, though ([docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell)). Unless `npm` has a `0` exit status when it fails, it should still exit on error.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks, that made me realize this only occurs on Windows runners. I updated the answer.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense!

Comment: I created a test repo here and it demonstrates the behaviour https://github.com/dsherret/gh_fail_fast_test/actions/runs/4513886968

Answer (score 1):

You should try the "and" operator (&&):

```
run: |
  npm install &&
  npm run test &&
  npm run e2e &&
  npm run deploy
```